# build of veins_inet failed

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I am using OMNeT++ 5.4.1, Veins 4.7.1 and INET 4.0.0.

When I am trying to build the `veins_inet` subproject it gives the following errors

[image]

Comment: sir, I am using veins 4.7.1 and inet 4.0.0. I also added inet as the reference for veins_inet in omnet++.  To be specific I downloaded the source from Github repositories with the latest commits. Please help me.

Comment: I want to use ManetRouter.ned(https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/node/inet/ManetRouter.ned) in veins. How can i use it? I mean is there a way to use inet 4.0.0 files in veins?

Comment: This appears to be a different question. If you consider this question answered, please provide the solution and mark it as "answered". Then, kindly open a new question wrt. presence of this feature in INET 3 or compatibility of INET 4 with Veins.

Comment: i did as you said sir, can you please answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52490453/how-to-use-manetrouter-ned-with-veins. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are using incompatible software versions.

Veins 4.7.1 works with INET 3.6.0 (not INET 4.0.0).

A full list of compatible software versions is available on the [download page of the Veins website](http://veins.car2x.org/download/).