# How to use ManetRouter.ned with veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I want to use ManetRouter.ned(https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/node/inet/ManetRouter.ned) in veins. How can i use it?

I mean is there a way to use inet 4.0.0 files in veins as veins is compatable with inet 3.6.4 only?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Veins master @[bfdfc10](https://github.com/sommer/veins/commits/bfdfc10) is compatible with INET 4.0.0. Note, however, that linking against INET 4.0.0 on Windows appears to be impossible. [Issue #379 of the INET framework](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/issues/379) is tracking this bug. You might have to wait for the next INET version. A workaround is to build Veins on Linux or to download [Instant Veins](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/instant-veins/).

Alternatively, you can either backport ManetRouter to INET 3 yourself, or forward-port ManetRouter from [the INETMANET project](https://github.com/inetmanet/inetmanet) to INET 3.